# How does big O notation indicate upper bound on a function?

Tags: big-o

Suppose we have a function, f(n)=n+10.
We say that f(n)∈O(n), meaning O(n) represents the upper bound of the function.

It is also true that f(n)∈O(n<sup>2</sup>) or f(n)∈O(n<sup>3</sup>) and so on.

So how can we say that O(n) is the upper bound when O(n<sup>2</sup>) is comparatively bigger bound and O(n<sup>3</sup>) is much bigger bound?

Please forgive if I have understood the concept wrongly.

Comment: I somehow could not get an answer through the link you provided. I would really appreciate if you could explain the answer to my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please follow the former given link to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Comment: The least upper bound on that function is O(1).

Comment: @Snowman: No, the least upper bound on `f(n)=n+10` is `O(n)` (i.e., the upper+lower bound, i.e. `f(n) ∈ Θ(n)`).  Big O notation defined as being applied to functions, not execution times.

Answer (score 15):

It is very easy to eliminate your confusion because it comes from a single word:

> O(n) represents **the** upper bound of the function.

That's incorrect. The correct statement is:

> O(n) represents **an** upper bound of the function.

Big-O notation does not mean that the function named in the notation is the *least upper bound*, just that it is *an upper bound*.

When we rewrite your question as:

> How can we say that O(n) is **an** upper bound when O(n<sup>2</sup>) is comparatively bigger bound and O(n<sup>3</sup>) is much bigger bound?

the question becomes clear.  There are no humans taller than 100 meters tall; that's an upper bound on human height.  200 meters and 10000000 meters are also upper bounds; the existence of larger upper bounds does not mean that a smaller upper bound is not also an upper bound. None of these are *the least upper bound*.

Now, in your example O(n) happens to be the *least* upper bound on the function you give. There are also larger upper bounds, as you note, and therefore those are not the *least* upper bounds.

Comment: +1 for addressing only the one detail of Big-O that OP was confused about: The non-uniqueness of upper bounds.
As a slight improvement, it'd be nice to see an explicit contrast of "upper bound" with "maximum", since OP may have assumed those are synonymous.

Comment: Actually, the *least* upper bound on `f(x)=x+10` is O(1), as the execution time of the function is independent of the value of `x`.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: That is incorrect.  O(1) is defined as being applied to functions, not execution times.

Comment: @Brian: Perhaps we use different interpretations of the term "function" here. The function that calculates the value of `x+10` has constant complexity (O(1)). An algorithm whose complexity is described by the function `n+10` has linear complexity (O(n)). When talking about algorithm/function complexity, the default is how it scales in time (i.e. execution time), although space complexity is also possible.

Comment: @Brian: I see your point. I interpreted the question as being "I have a program whose cost is `f(n) = n + 10`, which is `O(n)`. I think you are interpreting the question as "I have the program fragment `(int n) => n + 10`, which I agree is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

f(n) = O(g(n)) states that if there exists some constant c>0 and n<sub>0</sub>>0, then f(n) <= cg(n) for all n >= n<sub>0</sub>. Here n<sub>0</sub> is a limit above which we consider n i.e. we try to find asymptotic notation that itself means that we want to find time complexity for large values of n. So, we consider n<sub>0</sub> as lower limit of n and above n<sub>0</sub> this statement holds.

So, you have misunderstood that O(g(n)) with O(n), if we have two function with time complexity f(n<sub>1</sub>) = O(n<sub>1</sub>) and f(n<sub>2</sub>)= O(n<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) then there is a property of Big-O which is O(resulting function) = max(O(n<sub>1</sub>),O(n<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>)). So, by this in this case O(n<sup>2</sup>) is upper bound in comparison to O(n).